# Polymer force a paper-input to uppercase

Tags: polymer, web-component

Hi i'me trying to find a way to have a paper-input auto uppercase the input.
Do someone know where to start. Is writing a bahaviour a sollution?

Comment: The paper-input has an autocapitalize property.

Answer (score 2):

As the commens have stated the CSS solution without mixins won't work if shadow dom is enabled so, the solution using mixins:

```
<paper-input class="uppercase2"></paper-input>
```

And define a custom style on the input using the mixin **--paper-input-container-input:**:

```
<style is="custom-style">
    paper-input.uppercase2 {
       --paper-input-container-input: {                
          text-transform:uppercase;
       }
    }     
</style>
```

You can see it running in:
https://jsfiddle.net/0u45v46e/5/

Comment: This solution won't work with Shadow DOM. Unless you use `/deep/` that is, which is not a good idea

Comment: Even though I prefer not to use shadow dom, with mixins you can do it with CSS, you can find an example in here: [with and without mixins](https://jsfiddle.net/0u45v46e/4/)

Comment: @stp18 Your `without mixin case` will fail if `shadow-dom` is turned on ie why its better to use mixin

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way is to have an observer, which will upper case the input value?

A behaviour is of course an option to make the `toUpper` function reusable.

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'my-elem',
  properties: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      value: 'I will alwasy be upper case',
      observer: 'toUpper'
    }
  },
  toUpper: function(val) {
    this.value = val.toUpperCase();
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"/>  
  <link href="paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import"/>
</head>

<body>
  <my-elem></my-elem>
  
  <dom-module id="my-elem">
    <template>
      <paper-input value="{{value}}"></paper-input>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the other mix-in example working but after digging through the [source code on Github](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/master/paper-input-container.html) I got the following code to work:

```
<custom-style>
  <style is="custom-style">
    paper-input.custom {
      --paper-input-container-shared-input-style: {
        text-transform: uppercase;
      };
    }
  </style>
</custom-style>
<div>
  <paper-input always-float-label class="custom" label="The label">
  </paper-input>
</div>
```